# how to suppress warning message using silence_warnings in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My script need to ssh to a remote server and then it runs some shell commands on the remote server. It is able to connect and run the shell command but before doing that while trying to ssh it was giving a long warning message. 
So I tried to compress it by using "silence_warnings" but looks like it is suppressing that `Net::SSH.start` line and printing the rescue block message even if I have the correct login credentials.

```
@hostname = "SERVER_NAME"
@username = "user"
@password = "pass"
@cmd = "ls -alt"

begin
  silence_warnings do
    @ssh = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password)
  end

  puts "#{@ssh}"
  res = @ssh.exec!(@cmd)
  @ssh.close
  puts res
rescue
  puts "Unable to connect to #{@hostname} using #{@username}/#{@password}"
end
```

Need some guidance in fixing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does `silence_warnings` come from? It's not a standard Ruby method. What is the exception being raised (do `rescue => ex` and then `p ex`)? I have a feeling it's `NoMethodError`.

Comment: It's an ActiveSupport method http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-silence_warnings

Comment: I added the lines in `rescue` and removed "silence_warnings" from my code. But as per my understanding `rescue` block will handle only the exceptions or errors but not the warning message which are printing on the screen. I want to hide these warning messages. Is there any other way to do this?